# Discord.js: is there a partial to list new reactions on old messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

`` channelBackgroundCheck.send(`${reaction.users.cache.last()}, your account is being reviewed. Please standby.`) ``

When I run the code and execute the if statement by reacting on a message it sends this to the channel `undefined, your account is being reviewed. Please standby.` After I delete the reaction and react again it properly mentions my name. I already have 2 partials from which I thought they would cover this
`if (reaction.partial)` & `if (reaction.message.partial)`. Is it possible to initially properly display the user's name who reacted?

I'm using the master version of Discord.js. Here's my code:

```
   if (emoji.name == '✅') {
        if (reaction.partial) {
            try {
                await reaction.fetch();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Something went wrong when fetching the reaction: ', error);
            }
        }
        if (reaction.message.partial) {
            // If the message was removed the fetching might result in an API error, which we need to handle
            try {
                await reaction.message.fetch();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            }
        }
            message.guild.members.fetch(user.id).then(member => {
                    member.roles.add('679017985905786884');
                    member.roles.remove('678920391863042048');
            const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('678723590631325716')
            const channelBackgroundCheck = guild.channels.cache.get('678746066681724928')
            channelBackgroundCheck.send(`${reaction.users.cache.last()}, your account is being reviewed. Please standby.`)
            const channelFrontexStaff = guild.channels.cache.get('679082070081011773')
            channelFrontexStaff.send(`${reaction.users.cache.last()}, has joined the server. Their account is created on ${user.createdAt.toLocaleDateString("nl-NL")}`)
            const now = new Date();
                now.setMilliseconds(0);
                now.setSeconds(0);
                now.setMinutes(0);
                now.setHours(0);
                console.log(now);
            const accountCreation = user.createdAt;
                accountCreation.setMilliseconds(0);
                accountCreation.setSeconds(0);
                accountCreation.setMinutes(0);
                accountCreation.setHours(0);
                console.log(accountCreation);
            if(now - accountCreation < (86400000 * 7) /* one day multiplied by desired amount of days */) {
                channelFrontexStaff.send(`⚠️  ${reaction.users.cache.last()} has a new account.`)
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you need fetch message data for this. This is the nice [guide](https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/raw-events) how to easy solve your problem

Comment: dead link (404)